# How to make Yahoo Messenger work?

Tags: instant-messaging, yahoo

Just curious if anyone has had any luck or made any progress getting Yahoo Messenger to work with Ubuntu?  I know empathy and Viber and a lot of other work, but there are parts of Yahoo that make it a better fit for some of the people I am trying to convince to switch to Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

The best you can get currently seems to be [gyache](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gyachi/). Even though it is old and not maintained anymore. From the [website](http://gyachi.sourceforge.net/intro.shtml):

> This Yahoo! client for Linux operating system supports almost all of the features you would expect to find on the official Windows Yahoo! client: Voice chat, webcams, faders, 'nicknames', audibles, avatars, display images, and more. Yet, it remains very light-weight and memory-friendly. GyachE Improved uses Gtk-2 for its user interfaces (Gtk-2 2.0.6 or better required).

You need to install from [source](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gyachi/files/gyachi/1.1.71/gyachi-1.1.71.tar.gz/download?use_mirror=freefr&download=) though. From install.txt:

Steps for building a gyachi executable

1. use the autogen script to generate a configure script:

   ```
   ./autogen.sh
   ```
2. run configure, with any options that you might prefer:

   ```
   ./configure --disable-rpath --enable-maintainer-mode --prefix /usr
   ```
3. To generate a spec file

   ```
   make gyachi.spec
   ```
4. To build an image that will be installed over existing executables
   (not recommended):

   ```
   make
   make install
   ```

Answer (score 0):

**Pidgin**

You can also use Pidgin for meeseging in Yahoo.

Can installed with :

```
sudo apt-get install pidgin
```